# htaccess and htpasswd issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, .htpasswd

i'm having an issue with setting up htaccess and htpasswd for a specific folder on my web server. I have exhausted all material and answers that currently exist on stackoverflow and have got no where. This is the best guide I have found https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles which I have been using and this is what I have done so far;

I have modified the apache2.conf file adding in the following at the bottom;

```
<Directory "/var/www/resultparse/">
AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>
```

I have created the .htaccess file in the /var/www/resultparse/ directory;

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/resultparse/.htpasswd
AuthName "Authorization Required"
AuthType Basic
Require admin john
```

I have generated the .htpasswd file using the following commands adding the users john and admin;

```
htpasswd -c /var/www/resultparse/.htpasswd john
htpasswd /var/www/resultparse/.htpasswd admin
```

Which results in the following file being generated;

```
john:$apr1$we8lGQTG$dU2ZxXowyQSZKIQ3m2RU/.
admin:$apr1$mps05AMa$IGH9HBOWxO.CyU7SmuvND.
```

Finally I have restarted the apache server using `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload` so that the new configuration is loaded.

The result of this is that when I visit a page in this folder I get prompted with a login box however if i specify the user as admin and password as admin (what i set it to) it prompts me again for a user and password making me think that it's not matching the username and password in the file.

I thought originally it may be a permission issue on the files so i modified the permission of the .htpasswd and .htaccess file to be 777 but no luck.

Interestingly if I modify the require field of .htaccess to:
 `Require valid-user`
Then I do not get the dialogue box prompting me for the password.

Also if i change the `AuthUserFile` in the .htaccess to an incorrect path I get a internal server error when visiting the page proving that its finding the .htpasswd file.

Any help or suggestions on how to debug this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a `user` entity designation for the [`Require` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require).

Try changing that line to:

```
Require user admin john
```

Also, since you're allowing either user to log in, you could also try just doing:

```
Require valid-user
```

Comment: If I use the Require valid-user i no longer even get prompted with the dialogue box.

Comment: @JohnB have you restarted your browser? (or tried a different one)

Answer (score 1):

**Did you try turning it on and off again?**

I don't believe this! Restarted the browser and cleared history and it started working. No other changes made. Over two hours wasted.